# Error when clipping a raster and saving it to a gdb other than the Default.gdb

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, clip

I have several large Raster-Datasets stored in a Geodatabase (Example.gdb). I created polygon-shapefiles to clip the Rasters to the extend which I actually need. This works fine, as long as I save the output to the Default.gdb, whenever I want to save it to the other GDB (Example.gdb) I get an Error. Also I get an Error when I try to import the new Raster-Datasets from Default.gdb into Example.gdb.

Obviously I want to keep all the Data for this Projekt in one GDB.

Comment: How are you creating Example.gdb? What is the complete path to Example.gdb? Try placing it in the same folder as Default.gdb

Comment: @BERA I did not create Example.gdb myself. This was how I recieved the data. I stored it on our server, so that it is backed up in case of data loss. The Default.gdb is instead stored locally on the computer. I'll try as you suggested once the PC is available for me again.

Comment: @BERA Your suggestion solved my Problem! Thank you. I guess I wil simply copy the gdb to the server after every session. Do you have an explanation what causes the error when the Example.gdb is stored on the server or why the memory location of gdb is of importance?

Comment: Nice! No I dont know, could it be that you dont have the right permissions to write data to the server?